# Buefy Steps only show 1 b-step-item when viewing in Mobile view

Tags: vue.js, buefy

Hi i am a newbie in Vuejs, Buefy. I am implementing a Buefy Steps UI. in Desktop Version all the b-step-item are showing but when viewing to mobile version. only one b-step-item is showing (which is the current active one) i want show all b-step-item when viewing in mobile version. Is it possible? Can anyone guide me? Thank you.

Here is the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-star-odrvu?file=/src/App.vue:337-348

[image: It showing like this when viewing in mobile version]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `mobile-mode` to `null` and it will keep the same behavior as desktop.

```
:mobile-mode="null"
```

https://buefy.org/documentation/steps#api-view